# Extracting strings based on values of rows/columns

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 Response    1       2       3        4       SelectedAnswerString 

   3        dog     cat    mouse   rabbit    

   2        cap    light   watch    bag `
```

Would it be possible for me to extract the numerical value (e.g. 3) from the column titled "response" and select the column based on that numerical value (i.e. the column titled "3") to extract the string in that row/column (i.e. mouse for the first row) and create a new column with that string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas `dataframe.append(your value, ignore_index=True)` , so ignore_index argument says not to use the index labels. And if you want to extract the value you can use `.loc and .iloc`

Answer (score 0):

Using `df` as your dataframe, you can start with the idea of using the value in the `Response` column to identify the location of the column position, and grab that string in that column position to insert in the new column:

```
import pandas as pd

df[SelectedAnswerString] = df[df.iloc[:, df.Response]]
```

This assumes a numerical value for the `Response` column.  However, you'll need to adjust for the fact that Python starts indexing a 0